# UIElement to PNG - Text slightly blurred

Tags: silverlight, png, writeablebitmap, uielement

I am using ImageTool's PNG encoder to create an image.

I have a `Grid` that contains multiple `TextBlock`s, each `TextBlock` contains dynamic text.

When I create a `WriteableBitmap` from the grid containing the `TextBlock`s, I then use ImageTool's encoder to convert the `WriteableBitmap` to a PNG image.

All works well, however, when I view the PNG image (am saving the file to the hard drive for testing purposes) - the text looks slightly blurred.  Is this an issue with the encoder or the `WriteableBitmap` class?  And - has anyone experienced this before and are there workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a part of ImageTool project but I'm playing as a tester since I'm using this library in one of my project... If you can create a sample then you can probably show us so that we can test in our machine.

You can also try with Joe Stegman's encoder or fJCore JPEG encoder.